# How to find documents inside ref object without an id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two documents in mongodb:

```
export const Category = mongoose.model('Category', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
}));

export const SubCategory = mongoose.model('SubCategory', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
}));
```

How to find All SubCategory that match Category by name?

I have try a lot of ways but I always getting null or error...

```
var name = '...';

SubCategory.find({ category: { name } });

SubCategory.find({ category: { name } }).populate('category');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for the same. Please read this documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

Note:- This answer is based on your collection and data you have entered. this is not perfect but this will help best to find the logic from this answer. :-)

```
   //collection 1 schema
    const collection1Schema = new Schema({
     user_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
     },
     status: {
      type: String
     }
    });
    mongoose.model('Collection1', collection1Schema);
    //collection 2 schema
    const collection2Schema = new Schema({
     user_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user_id'
     },
     item: {
      type: String
     }
    });
    mongoose.model('Collection2', collection2Schema);
    //find data from collection2
    Collection2.find()
     .populate('user_id')
     .exec(function(err, foundDocuments) {
      if (error) {
       console.error(err);
      } else {
       console.log(foundDocuments);
      }
     });
```

For more info:- [Mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)